# In Python how to access elements of tuples using reduce()?

Tags: python, list-manipulation

I want to add the numbers 1,2,3 from the below list of tuples together. I tried:

```
reduce(lambda (x,y),(z,t): y+t,[('a',1),('b',2),('c',3)])
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

How do I fix this error? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to add a list of tuples. Therefore your `lambda` must return a tuple (otherwise, how will you add one call's result to the next item?), and you must also use a starting value that is a tuple.  Something like this works:

```
reduce(lambda (x,y),(z,t): (0, y+t),[('a',1),('b',2),('c',3)], (0,0))[1]
```

You end up with a tuple `(0, 6)` and then use `[1]` to just get the `6`.

If that looks ugly, it's because `reduce` is not a great tool for this.  `sum` with a generator expression works much better:

```
sum(x[1] for x in [('a',1),('b',2),('c',3)])
```